# What is the name for this "divide and conquer" style of proof?

Tags: logic, terminology

Let's say there is some interesting but possibly complicated proposition `p` which I either do not know or is unknowable. However, if I assume it is true, I use that assumption to prove some interesting things (say, `a`, `b`, and `c`), and if I assume it is not true, I can use that prove a different set of interesting things (say, `b`, `d`, and `e`). In this example, I have proven `b`  with two different set of assumptions and collectively I know `p or not p`, so I have proven `b`.

In other words,

`p` implies `a`, `b`, and `c`

`not p` implies `b`, `d`, and `e`

Therefore, `b`

Does this style of proof have a name?

Comment: it is a tautology

Comment: One possibly important bit of context my new text adds that was missing (but could have been assumed) is that proposition `p`  and its negation factor into the proof of each arm. I don't know whether that would give rise to a more specific term.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think (now that this has been reopened) you can just post an answer saying it's proof by cases or proof by exhaustion, maybe adding a bit more context, so that this doesn't stay unanswered.